# x11 session and android

Tags: android, x11

is there a way to open a X11 session with an Android app?

My problem is that i want to run some graphical programs, installed on a debian server,
through an Android app.
But at the moment i have no idea on how to do it.

I'm searching a lot on the web, but i can't find a (good or partial) solution.

I have thought to open a X11 session between my app and the server...
But, is it realizable? (and how can i implement it?)

Or there are other ways to solve my problem?!

thanks a lot!!

...

Comment: Do you want to write the app or are you looking for an X server app of which there are several on Google Play.

Comment: I want to write an app...